# Show input field when specific option is selected from select box - Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

When I select on option, I want to show a input text tag.

**html code**

```
<ion-item >
   <ion-label floating>TIN/GRN NO</ion-label>
   <ion-select [(ngModel)]="num">
     <ion-option *ngFor="let nom of list" value="{{nom.value}}" checked="  {{nom.checked}}" [innerHTML]="nom.label">{{nom.text}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngIf="num == 'true'">
     <ion-label>Detail</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

**ts file**

```
num = 'true';
 list: Array<{ value: number, text: string, checked: boolean }> = [];

constructor:
        this.list.push({ value: 1, text: 'TIN NO', checked: false  });
        this.list.push({ value: 2, text: 'GRN NO' , checked: false });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing `<ion-select [(ngModel)]="num">` the `num` property will have the values *1* or *2* (not true or false) so in your view you need to compare against those values:

```
  <ion-item *ngIf="num == 1">
     <ion-label>Detail</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: Actually i have 2 options ,when i click any one of the option i want to show input text.In this case if i give num==1,if i select 1st option then only it give input text.for second option it didnt give input text.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the issue in your comment. You can show the input for more options like this `*ngIf="num == 1 || num == 2"`